# Interpolation with consistent speed

Tags: libgdx, interpolation

I'm making an multiplayer game and I bumped into a problem, I want to interpolate player position so it would not look jittery when player is having bigger ping/latency, I'm using vector2 interpolation but every single of the interpolation formula is decreasing/increasing speed in the middle/beginning/middle and I need so that interpolation speed would always be the same (so it would look like player is moving not floating)

Comment: i suggest that you take a look at this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/lag-compensation-with-networked-2d-games

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is the [dead reckoning alghoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) which is unfortunately [not supported by Libgdx](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1705) by default. There are many ways to implement this basing on what kind of game you are creating.

There is no one good answer for your question but let say you are making a simple runner where players are going forward and they can jump. The naive implementation for multiplayer like this would be to change opponent's position due to notification he is sending. Now you are interpolating the position between notifications however you should rather **assume that the opponent is still runing** and when get notification that he jumps then correct position and perform jump an so on...

There are dozens of articles about dead reckoning in the internet. You can [start with this one](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131638/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php).